# How do I increase transaction.completedTxTimeout in JBoss AS 7.1 Infinispan?

Tags: jboss7.x, infinispan

Our customer is running four standalone JBoss AS 7.1 nodes that are merged into a cluster by means of session replication and load balancer.

We are getting these errors often without additional details. I am also no expert in JBoss and I have exhausted all my Google-fu.

I don't personally have access to server configuration, nor has my technical *bridge* person. But we have right to ask questions.

```
2019-03-29 11:38:08 ERROR [org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor] (default task-15) ISPN000136: Error executing command CommitCommand, writing keys [0qsZ5PfJNsgD9SYAjeyMLeSrEXJVGbtuwVgwtjd-, 0qsZ5PfJNsgD9SYAjeyMLeSrEXJVGbtuwVgwtjd-]: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from xxxxxx:stc00Server2373, see cause for remote stack trace
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.AbstractTransport.checkResponse(AbstractTransport.java:44) [infinispan-core-8.1.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:8.1.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.checkRsp(JGroupsTransport.java:766) [infinispan-core-8.1.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:8.1.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.lambda$invokeRemotelyAsync$1(JGroupsTransport.java:615) [infinispan-core-8.1.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:8.1.6.Final-redhat-1]
    ........
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups.ClassLoaderThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0(ClassLoaderThreadFactory.java:52)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: ISPN000362: Could not find status for remote transaction GlobalTransaction:<xxxxxx:stc00Server2374>:5359:remote, please increase transaction.completedTxTimeout
    at org.infinispan.commands.tx.CommitCommand.invalidRemoteTxReturnValue(CommitCommand.java:52) [infinispan-core-8.1.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:8.1.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.infinispan.commands.tx.AbstractTransactionBoundaryCommand.perform(AbstractTransactionBoundaryCommand.java:89) [infinispan-core-8.1.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:8.1.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.infinispan.remoting.inboundhandler.BasePerCacheInboundInvocationHandler.invokePerform(BasePerCacheInboundInvocationHandler.java:92) [infinispan-core-8.1.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:8.1.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.infinispan.remoting.inboundhandler.BaseBlockingRunnable.run(BaseBlockingRunnable.java:34) [infinispan-core-8.1.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:8.1.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.ClassLoaderThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0(ClassLoaderThreadFactory.java:48) [wildfly-clustering-infinispan-extension-7.0.4.GA-redhat-2.jar:7.0.4.GA-redhat-2]
    ... 1 more

2019-03-29 11:38:08 ERROR [org.infinispan.transaction.impl.TransactionCoordinator] (default task-15) ISPN000188: Error while processing a commit in a two-phase transaction: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from xxxxx:stc00Server2373, see cause for remote stack trace
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.AbstractTransport.checkResponse(AbstractTransport.java:44) [infinispan-core-8.1.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:8.1.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.checkRsp(JGroupsTransport.java:766) [infinispan-core-8.1.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:8.1.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.lambda$invokeRemotelyAsync$1(JGroupsTransport.java:615) [infinispan-core-8.1.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:8.1.6.Final-redhat-1]
    .....
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups.ClassLoaderThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0(ClassLoaderThreadFactory.java:52)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: ISPN000362: Could not find status for remote transaction GlobalTransaction:<xxxxx:stc00Server2374>:5359:remote, please increase transaction.completedTxTimeout
    at org.infinispan.commands.tx.CommitCommand.invalidRemoteTxReturnValue(CommitCommand.java:52) [infinispan-core-8.1.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:8.1.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.infinispan.commands.tx.AbstractTransactionBoundaryCommand.perform(AbstractTransactionBoundaryCommand.java:89) [infinispan-core-8.1.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:8.1.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.infinispan.remoting.inboundhandler.BasePerCacheInboundInvocationHandler.invokePerform(BasePerCacheInboundInvocationHandler.java:92) [infinispan-core-8.1.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:8.1.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.infinispan.remoting.inboundhandler.BaseBlockingRunnable.run(BaseBlockingRunnable.java:34) [infinispan-core-8.1.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:8.1.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.ClassLoaderThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0(ClassLoaderThreadFactory.java:48) [wildfly-clustering-infinispan-extension-7.0.4.GA-redhat-2.jar:7.0.4.GA-redhat-2]
    ... 1 more
```

I have not just redacted references to customer, but also redundant rows. The full stack trace is available [as a paste](https://pastebin.com/rQGEn25X).

In our environment, where we are unable to replicate the issue, the best I could find that configures Infinispan is the following block:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:4.0">
        <cache-container name="server" aliases="singleton cluster" default-cache="default" module="org.wildfly.clustering.server">
            <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
            <replicated-cache name="default" mode="SYNC">
                <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
            </replicated-cache>
        </cache-container>
        <cache-container name="web" default-cache="repl" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
            <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
            <replicated-cache name="repl" mode="SYNC">
                <locking isolation="READ_COMMITTED"/>
                <transaction locking="OPTIMISTIC" mode="BATCH"/>
                <file-store/>
            </replicated-cache>
        </cache-container>
        <cache-container name="manager" default-cache="repl" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
            <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
            <replicated-cache name="repl" mode="SYNC">
                <locking isolation="READ_COMMITTED"/>
                <transaction locking="OPTIMISTIC" mode="BATCH"/>
                <file-store/>
            </replicated-cache>
        </cache-container>
        <cache-container name="ejb" aliases="sfsb" default-cache="dist" module="org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan">
            <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
            <distributed-cache name="dist" mode="ASYNC" l1-lifespan="0" owners="2">
                <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
                <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                <file-store/>
            </distributed-cache>
        </cache-container>
        <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query" module="org.hibernate.infinispan">
            <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
            <local-cache name="local-query">
                <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <invalidation-cache name="entity" mode="SYNC">
                <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
            </invalidation-cache>
            <replicated-cache name="timestamps" mode="ASYNC"/>
        </cache-container>
    </subsystem>
```

Question is: where is this parameter (`transaction.completedTxTimeout`) configured in JBoss `standalone.xml`? That seems to point at [this attribute](http://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/7.1/apidocs/org/infinispan/configuration/cache/TransactionConfigurationBuilder.html#completedTxTimeout(long))

Comment: As with any timeouts, you should check GC logs and get thread dumps to see if there's anything that might hint the cause. Hard to say what's the cause, but that's a fairly old JBoss AS version. I'd highly recommend an upgrade to the latest WildFly or EAP version (which replaces JBoss AS). Also, if your customers depend on this and you lack the experience, you might want to consider professional support ;)

Comment: `I'd highly recommend an upgrade` -> sorry but it is not possible. Customer uses **that** version, we must stick to that. My boss does not fund for any professional support. I am the support person here

Comment: Then you have little choice other than looking deeper into what's up with GC, thread dumps...etc and see if anything similar in our [issue tracking JIRA](https://issues.jboss.org/projects/ISPN/summary). You will at some point need to upgrade the customer, so the more streamline that process the better off you'll be in the future.